# PDE for Pricing Interest Rate Derivatives

Tags: stochastic-processes, bond, martingale, differential-equations, stochastic-discount

Suppose that interest rate $r(t)$ follows some short-rate models, say Vasicek, so that$dr = a(b-r) dt + \sigma dZ$, with constants $a,b,\sigma$.

It is well known that the price of zero-coupon bond $P(r,t)$ at current time $t$ maturing at $T$ with face value 1 follows (for example, see McDonald's Derivatives Markets, 3rd ed, p.758):
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial r^2} + a(b-r) \frac{\partial P}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} - r P=0$$
with boundary condition $P(r,T) = 1$.
Note that we could write $P(r,t) = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q} \Big[ e^{- \int_t^T r(u)  du} \big| F_t \Big]$ for all $t \leq T$.

Trying to generalize, for some smooth condition of $h(r,T)$ depending only on $r$ at $T$: If we define $Q(r,t) = \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q} \Big[ e^{- \int_t^T r(u)  du} h(r,T) \big| F_t \Big]$ for all $t \leq T$, does the following PDE
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial r^2} + a(b-r) \frac{\partial Q}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} - r Q=0$$
with boundary condition $Q(r,T) = h(r,T)$ hold?

Comment: you mean $Q(t,T) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_t^T r(u) du} h(r_T)\right]$ ?

Comment: Hi, MJ73550, yes I mean $h(r, T)$, to be terminal condition for $Q$. Thanks.

Comment: My question is whether $h $ depends only on the final value of $r$ or the whole path.

Comment: $h$ depends only on final value $r$ at $T$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
\begin{align*}
M(r_t, t) &\equiv Q(r_t, t) e^{-\int_0^t r_u du} \\
&=E\left(e^{-\int_0^T r_u du} h(r_T, T) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right)
\end{align*}
is a martingale. Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
dM &= \frac{\partial M}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial M}{\partial r} dr_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 M}{\partial r^2}d\langle r, r\rangle_t\\
&=\left[\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} e^{-\int_0^t r_u du} - r_t Q(r_t, t) e^{-\int_0^t r_u du}\right]dt+e^{-\int_0^t r_u du}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial r}dr+ \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial r^2}e^{-\int_0^t r_u du}dt\\
&=e^{-\int_0^t r_u du}\left[\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial r^2} +a(b-r_t)\frac{\partial Q}{\partial r} -r_t Q(r_t, t) + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}  \right)dt + \sigma \frac{\partial Q}{\partial r} dZ \right].
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial r^2} +a(b-r_t)\frac{\partial Q}{\partial r} -r_t Q(r_t, t) + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}=0.
\end{align*}