# Bond dynamics in Ho Lee model

Tags: bond, short-rate

The short rate in the Ho-Lee model is given by :

$$dr_t=\left( \frac{df(0,t)}{dt} +\sigma^2t\right)dt + \sigma dW_t$$

I'm trying to find the bond dynamics given by :

$$dP(t,T)/P(t,T)=r_tdt-\sigma(T-t)dW_t$$

I started from :

$$P(t,T)=E_t[e^{-\int_t^T r_sds}]$$

and I applied Itô to the function $P(t,T)=\phi(t,r)$:

$$d\phi(t,r) = \frac{\partial \phi(t,r)}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial \phi(t,r)}{\partial r} dr_t+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2\phi(t,r)}{\partial r^2}(dr_t)^2$$

I computed the derivatives :

$$\frac{\partial \phi(t,r)}{\partial t}=r_tP(t,T)$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi(t,r)}{\partial r} = -(T-t)P(t,T)$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2\phi(t,r)}{\partial r^2} = (T-t)^2P(t,T)$$

Assembling everything I get :

$$dP(t,T)/P(t,T) = r_tdt-(T-t)\sigma dW_t +\left[ 
 \frac{1}{2}(T-t)^2\sigma^2-(T-t)\left( \frac{df(0,t)}{dt}+\sigma^2t \right) \right] dt $$

I don't know how to get rid of the last $dt$ term. Any Help? Or did I get the derivatives wrong? I checked them several times but I don't see where the probem comes from. Thank you

Comment: Have a look of [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15956/ho-and-lee-derivation-for-short-rates-model/15962#15962).

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the link, but that doesn't answer my question

Comment: You have the bond price formula, then you can derive the SDE.

Comment: I see your point. but what about showing that the second $dt$ term in my post is equal to zero?

Comment: Your derivative $\frac{\partial \phi(t,r)}{\partial t}$ does not appear correct. When you take the derivative, you need to be mindful for the conditional expectation.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to do it right? I mean that derivative

Comment: I already have the bond price formula there, are you able to take the partial derivative based on that?

Comment: Looks like I can't as I did it wrong. Don't bother if it is that hard for you to just show how to do it

Answer (score 3):

When taking the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ in a conditional expectation, not only the parameter $t$ within the expectation needs to be considered, the information set $\mathscr{F}_t$ should also be considered.

For this particular question, based on an answer to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15956/ho-and-lee-derivation-for-short-rates-model/15962#15962),
\begin{align*}
P(t, T) = e^{-(T-t)r_t - \int_t^T (T-u)\theta_u du + \frac{\sigma^2}{6}(T-t)^3},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\theta_t &= \frac{df(0,t)}{dt} +\sigma^2t.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial P(t, T)}{\partial t} &= P(t, T)\Big(r_t + (T-t) \theta_t -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)^2\Big)\\
&= P(t, T)\Big(r_t + (T-t) \Big(\frac{df(0,t)}{dt} +\sigma^2t\Big) -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)^2\Big).
\end{align*}
The remaining is now straightforward.

Comment: *"When taking the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ in a conditional expectation, not only the parameter $t$ within the expectation needs to be considered, the information set $\mathscr{F}_t$ should also be considered."* Can you suggest good reading material on this topic. Namely how to take find derivatives of expectations and conditional expectation?

Comment: Have a look of [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41322/ho-lee-model-in-baxterrennie?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, I would not suggest this in practice, instead, you can compute the conditional expectation first, and then take the derivative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to show how to take the derivative of the conditional expectation directly as I tried to do? That way you will correct me as clearly I'm doing something really wrong

Comment: If you write down the partial derivative by the definition, you will know where you were wrong.