# Why don't I get this right $\frac{d}{dt}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[ e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}|\mathscr{F}_t \right]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $r$ a random process defined by :

$$dr_t=\theta(t)dt + \sigma dW_t$$

$\theta$ is deterministic in $t$ and $W$ a brownian motion.

I don't know where my calculation below is going wrong :

Let $R=\int r(s)ds$

then :
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[  e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}|\mathscr{F}_t \right] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[ \frac{d}{dt} e^{-(R_T - R_t)}|\mathscr{F}_t \right] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[ r(t) e^{-(R_T - R_t)}|\mathscr{F}_t \right] = r(t) \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[  e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}|\mathscr{F}_t \right]$$

But regarding this question [Bond dynamics in Ho Lee model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44002/bond-dynamics-in-ho-lee-model) my computation is not correct

Any help please?

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: Regarding this question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44002/bond-dynamics-in-ho-lee-model my computation is not correct

Comment: Your first equality is wrong. It is true that you can bring the derivative inside the expectation operator due to Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem (the function is bounded). However, you need to find the solution of the SDE for $r_t$ and then compute the mean of this Gaussian variable.

Comment: @JohnLord then update your question to clarift. Also your notation is bad: do you wish to calculate partial derivative or total derivative ? Those are not the same.

Comment: @FunnyBuzer why do you need the solution of $r_t$ SDE? after the derivative, the resulting $r_t$ is know given $F_t$ and we can simply take it out of the expectation. No?

Comment: If you express the partial derivative by definition, you will know where you were wrong. Note that you have $t$ in two places. Why do you ignore the other one?

Comment: @JohnLord I suggest you revise the Leibniz integral rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @FunnyBuzer I didn't think of applying Leibniz formally in this example and I find it hard to do since the filtration is t-dependent. Can you show me how to do it taking into account the t-dependcy of the filtration?

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggest you solve the integral first, take the expectation (note that you'll have the a Gaussian integral in the exponent) and then differentiate. My answer below is a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the stochastic integration by parts to solve the integral inside the expectation:
$$\int_t^Tr_sds=Tr_T-tr_t-\int_t^Tsdr_s=(T-t)r_t+\int_t^T(T-s)\underbrace{dr_s}_{:=\theta(s)ds+\sigma dW_s}$$
Solve this integral and then take the expectation and solve the derivative.
For a complete answer see [Ho and lee derivation for short rates model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15956/ho-and-lee-derivation-for-short-rates-model/15962#15962).