# Term structure equation in the Vasicek model

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, differential-equations, vasicek

Consider the SDE $$dr_t = (b-ar_t)dt +\sigma dW_t, \text{with } a; b > 0.$$ Let $$F(t; r) = E(\exp(-\int_{t}^{T}r_sds)| r_t = r).$$ (F can be interpreted as price of a zero coupon bond with maturity T.)

Use the Feynman-Kac
formula to derive a PDE for the function $F(t; r)$.

I wanted to use Ito to obtain formula for $r_t$ and then plug it into Feynman-Kac formula $$E_{t0,x}=(\exp(-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds)\phi(X_t))$$ from the lecture, but I can't derive it. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Use Ito's formula to write down an expression for $dF_u$. Then note that $F_T - F_t = \int_t^T dF_u du$. Plug in the expression for $dF_u$ and note that $F_t$ is the expectation of $F_T$.

Comment: Does [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30042/pde-for-pricing-interest-rate-derivatives/30082#30082) answer your question?